# How to add an image to a infowindow in Google Maps API

Tags: android, api, google-maps, infowindow

I'm trying to add pictures into my infowindows which appears when I click on the marker. I'm using the Google Maps API.

I want to achieve something like this:
[This is an example from the Google Documentation. Sadly, it's without example code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi0gN.png)

So can anyone help me? I would be very pleased if I could get some real code I can implement later into my application.

Note: I'm programming for Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

From the Google documentation on `InfoWindow`s (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows):

> You are also able to customize the contents and design of info windows. To do this, you must create a concrete implementation of the `InfoWindowAdapter` interface and then call `GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()` with your implementation.

From the documentation for `InfoWindowAdapter` (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter):

> When constructing an info window, methods in this class are called in a defined order. **To replace the default info window**, override `getInfoWindow(Marker)` with your custom rendering and return `null` for `getInfoContents(Marker)`. **To replace only the info window contents** inside the default info window frame (the callout bubble), return `null` in `getInfoWindow(Marker)` and override `getInfoContents(Marker)` instead.

Both methods simply return a `View`, so you can add an image to your info window by returning any viewgroup that contains an image.

Comment: hmm, this looks interesting. But I don't understand completely, where I have to add what exactly. Android Studio doesn't even recognise 'getInfoContent'

Comment: Would it help, If I would post my .java file so you could give me a simple example or explaination directly into my code?